# Adicionar valores onclick()

Tags: php, jquery, html

Eu tenho este código:

```
var tudo=0;
function muda(a){
  o=$("#"+a).attr("data-ocupado");
  var t = $("#gasto").html();
  if(o==1){
    alert("Lugar já Ocupado!");
  }else{
  p=$("#"+a).attr("data-preco");
  var confirma = confirm("Deseja alugar este lugar? \n Preço: "+p+"€");
  if(confirma == true){
    tudo = parseInt(p+t);
    alert(p);
    $("#"+a).attr("data-ocupado", "1");
  $('#'+a).css({
        'color': 'red'
    });
    $("#gasto").html(tudo)
  }
}
}
```

Com este html e php

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
  <?php
  $a=0;
  while($a<300){
    $a++;
    if($a%5==0){
      $vazio="&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }else{
      $vazio="";
    }
    if($a%50==0){
      $extra ="<br>";
    }else{
      $extra="";
    }
    $preco=rand(0, 40);
  ?>
  <span style="background-color:silver;color:black;cursor:pointer;" data-ocupado="0" data-preco="<?=$preco; ?>" id="<?=$a; ?>" onclick="muda(<?=$a; ?>)"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span><?=$vazio; ?><?=$extra; ?>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Mas sempre que eu carrego noutro icone, era suposto incrementar o preço a todos os outros preços que tinhas sido carregados antes, mas inves disso, vai adicionando os valores extensamente na div com o id = "gasto"

Comment: Campo de pergunta é para pergunta e campo de respostas é para respostas. Não tem como ser mais claro que isso. Lembre-se que o [pt.so] não é um fórum. Aliás, faça o [tour] para aprender o básico do site. E faça logo, para evitar qualquer possível constrangimento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você mesmo descobriu, o problema é que ao fazer:

```
var t = $("#gasto").html();
var p = $("#"+a).attr("data-preco");
```

Ambas as variáveis serão do tipo *string*, por exemplo, `"1"` e `"5"`, respectivamente. Se você apenas tentar somá-los, tal como em:

```
tudo = parseInt(p+t);
```

Ficará:

```
tudo = parseInt("1" + "5");
```

No JavaScript, o operador `+` concatena duas *strings*. Portanto, ficaria:

```
tudo = parseInt("15") 
     = 15;
```

Para que a soma seja feita corretamente, você precisa converter os valores para inteiros antes da operação:

```
tudo = parseInt(p) + parseInt(t);
     = parseInt("1") + parseInt("5");
     = 1 + 5;
     = 6;
```